# Who or what start polkitd in Slackware?

Tags: slackware, polkit

On Linux "who" start daemons?

Suse, RockyLinux, Debian use systemd

Devuan use scripts in /etc/rc*.d/* which are symlinks from /etc/init.d

Slackware: use scripts in /etc/rc.d/rc.* (for example rc.M start a lot of daemons, rc.sshd start sshd, etc..)

On my Slackware I see polkitd start at the boot.
But who or what start it?

```
ps -ef|grep pol
polkitd   2210     1  0 set04 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/polkit-1/polkitd --no-debug
```

polkit is not defined in any script

```
grep -irl polkit /etc/rc.d/
grep -irl polkit /etc/init.d
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Slackware, it is started by `dbus-daemon`, which in turn is started by `rc.d/rc.messagebus`.